# Have to copy 4 to 12 months records from MAIN_TABLE to ARCHIVE table

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

Am using cursor

```
  CURSOR c_process_state is
      SELECT service, tr_source, tr_id, action, tstamp 
        FROM process_state 
       WHERE tstamp BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(trunc(SYSDATE,'MONTH'), -4) 
         AND LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH') - 12);

 //followed by insert statements into the table process_state_archival
```

I am not able see the records between 4 and 12 months. It's not working properly.

I want to fetch the records between 4 and 12 months based on tstamp field.

And also I have to delete the records from 4 to 12 months once copying is successful.

Can any one please tell me how to add the condition? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you indeed want to select records from 4 months back in the past to 12 months in the past:

```
CURSOR c_process_state is
   SELECT service, tr_source, tr_id, action, tstamp 
     FROM process_state 
    WHERE tstamp BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH')), - 12)
      AND ADD_MONTHS(trunc(SYSDATE,'MONTH'), -4);
```

Comment: Can you please explain what is that LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE,'MONTH'),-4) and why we are giving ADD_MONTHS(---) in the first place ??? Is there any thing like FIRST_DAY required to get the correct records ??

Comment: `ADD_MONTHS(trunc(SYSDATE,'MONTH'), -4)`: this allows to select records that are 4 months old.

Comment: `ADD_MONTHS(LAST_DAY(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH')), - 12)`: this allows to select records that are one year old (12 months old), from the last day of current month

Comment: Thank you:) Got it.. My doubt here is Why LAST_DAY(----) ?? why not ADD_MONTH(---) ??

Comment: You might indeed remove the `last_day` if you want to get the 1 year  old records starting from today. I took the clause from your query, supposing that was what you wanted.

Comment: no. I want to copy records between 4 and 12 months, Not from starting today.

Answer (score 0):

Try with the below query, if you want to select the data between date range `01-APR AND 31-DEC`.

```
CURSOR c_process_state is
     SELECT service, tr_source, tr_id, action, tstamp 
     FROM   process_state 
     WHERE  tstamp
     BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(trunc(SYSDATE, 'YEAR'), 3) AND ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE ,'YEAR'), 12) -1
```